# Does neo4j desktop include a usable neo4j database

Tags: python, django, neo4j

I have installed neo4j desktop and I am able to use neo4j database from it. The problem is when I try to connect to neo4j database from a Django project.

I have configured my `settings.py` with `config.DATABASE_URL = 'bolt://neo4j:neo4j@localhost:7687'`, but when I run `neomodel_install-labels`, I get this error:

```
Connecting to bolt://neo4j:neo4j@localhost:7687

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/hugovillalobos/Documents/Code/AttractoraProject/AttractoraVenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/neo4j/bolt/connection.py",
line 578, in _connect
    s.connect(resolved_address)
ConnectionRefusedError: [Errno 61] Connection refused

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/hugovillalobos/Documents/Code/AttractoraProject/AttractoraVenv/bin/neomodel_install_labels", line 67, in <module>
    main()

  File "/Users/hugovillalobos/Documents/Code/AttractoraProject/AttractoraVenv/bin/neomodel_install_labels", line 62, in main
    db.set_connection(bolt_url)
  File "/Users/hugovillalobos/Documents/Code/AttractoraProject/AttractoraVenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/neomodel/util.py", line 65,
 in set_connection
    max_pool_size=config.MAX_POOL_SIZE)
  File "/Users/hugovillalobos/Documents/Code/AttractoraProject/AttractoraVenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/neo4j/v1/api.py", line 94,
in driver
    return Driver(uri, **config)
  File "/Users/hugovillalobos/Documents/Code/AttractoraProject/AttractoraVenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/neo4j/v1/api.py", line 133,
 in __new__
    return subclass(uri, **config)
  File "/Users/hugovillalobos/Documents/Code/AttractoraProject/AttractoraVenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/neo4j/v1/direct.py", line 7
3, in __new__
    pool.release(pool.acquire())
  File "/Users/hugovillalobos/Documents/Code/AttractoraProject/AttractoraVenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/neo4j/v1/direct.py", line 4
4, in acquire
    return self.acquire_direct(self.address)
  File "/Users/hugovillalobos/Documents/Code/AttractoraProject/AttractoraVenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/neo4j/bolt/connection.py",
line 453, in acquire_direct
    connection = self.connector(address, self.connection_error_handler)
  File "/Users/hugovillalobos/Documents/Code/AttractoraProject/AttractoraVenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/neo4j/v1/direct.py", line 7
0, in connector
    return connect(address, security_plan.ssl_context, error_handler, **config)
  File "/Users/hugovillalobos/Documents/Code/AttractoraProject/AttractoraVenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/neo4j/bolt/connection.py",
line 707, in connect
raise last_error
  File "/Users/hugovillalobos/Documents/Code/AttractoraProject/AttractoraVenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/neo4j/bolt/connection.py",
line 697, in connect
    s = _connect(resolved_address, **config)
  File "/Users/hugovillalobos/Documents/Code/AttractoraProject/AttractoraVenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/neo4j/bolt/connection.py",
line 587, in _connect
    raise ServiceUnavailable("Failed to establish connection to {!r} (reason {})".format(resolved_address, error.errno))
neo4j.exceptions.ServiceUnavailable: Failed to establish connection to ('::1', 7687, 0, 0) (reason 61)
```

I know the database is running because I can connect from **neo4j desktop**, and I have installed **neo4j-driver** and **neomodel**. I don't know what I am missing.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I don't know if this apply to any case, and I don't know the reason for it, but I found that it was a matter of spacial characters in the password. I set my password with an exclamation character, and when I was trying to connect, it failed. I changed the password for the user in Neo4j removing the exclamation character and Bingo! I got a connection. Can anybody tell my why this happens?